# Refilling Dye Ink Cartridge with Pigment ink?

Tags: canon, printing

will it print ? and how long ? the printer model is canon MG5140

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about using a printer without any specific photographic application.

Answer (score 1):

[Farbenwerk](http://www.farbenwerk.com) is a Germany-based producer of high quality replacement inks. There you can find pigment ink replacements for many dye printers, e.g. the Epson 1500W. Unfortunately, as can be seen from [here](http://www.farbenwerk.com/CANON_1__Pixma-MG-5140), it seems that they do not have pigment ink for the 5140. This is at least a hint that it is not possible to print pigment ink with this printer.